# How do I install a package with synaptic?

Tags: synaptic

I looked for some help, but the image and tips didn't fit my synaptic. Here is how my Synaptic Package Manager looks:

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

Answer (score 1):

1. To select package for installation - choose it on the right side and then:

   - do right mouse click and select *Mark for Installation*
   - use *Package* → *Mark for Installation* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).
2. To install already selected packages:

   - click on *Apply* button on the Toolbar
   - use *Edit* → *Apply Marked Changes* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
3. Review the list in opened window and click *Apply* button.